# Listview filtering and adapter

Tags: android, listview, view, filter, textwatcher

I have a `ListView` and I am overriding `getView` method which is populating properly with the following code. When I **don't** use `adapter.getFilter().filter(s)` it works, if I use it causes the error shown after the code. Any idea how can I enable filtering when I am overriding the `getView`?

```
lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
android.R.layout.activity_list_item,stringArray) 
{   @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {View  row= super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        View row=convertView;
if(position==5){
row = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_header, null);
final TextView sectionView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.list_item_section_text);
sectionView.setText(myList.get(position));
} 
return row;
}
});

myFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
}
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
}
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {             
adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
});
```

> > ERROR
> >       java.lang.NullPointerException
> >       at com.android.testdatabase.Listsort$2.onTextChanged(Listsort.java:215)
> >       at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:6131)
> >       at android.widget.TextView.handleTextChanged(TextView.java:6172)
> >       at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onTextChanged(TextView.java:6316)
> >       at >android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextChange(SpannableStringBuilder.java:889)
> >       at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.change(SpannableStringBuilder.java:352)
> >       at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.change(SpannableStringBuilder.java:269)
>
> at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:432)
>     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:409)
>     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:28)
>     at >android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.replaceText(BaseInputConnection.java:583)
>     at >android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.setComposingText(BaseInputConnection.java:384>)
>     at >com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.j>ava:292)
>     at >com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnection>Wrapper.java:73)
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
>     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>
> > 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You reference the variable "adapter" here:

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {             
adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
});
```

I don't see that you are actually setting that adapter to be equal to your adapter at any point.  I think you are getting a null pointer exception because this variable is not set.